# How do you use Object Oriented Programming to program a tortoise and the hare race in Python, more specifically, how do we get them to actually move?

Tags: python, oop

> Hi there! Right now we are trying to use object-oriented programming to make the tortoise and the hare race. We are coding in jupyter notebook with python3. This is what we have so far.
>
> This is the first part of the code and it seems like the way we get the animals to move is with the advance position method but we don't know what to put in there to get them to move. This will advance the position of the animal for a single second, based on the animal definition for speed and naptime.

```
class animal:
    time = 0
    
    def __init__(self, name, species, speed, napStart, napDuration, currentPosition):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.species = str(species)
        self.speed = int(speed)
        self.napStart = int(napStart)
        self.napDuration = int(napDuration)
        self.currentPosition = int(currentPosition)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + " " + str(self.species) + " " + str(self.speed) + " " + str(self.napStart) + " " + str(self.napDuration) + " " + str(self.currentPosition)
        
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    
    def getSpeed(self):
        return self.speed
    
    def getNapStart(self):
        return self.napStart
    
    def getNapDuration(self):
        return self.napDuration
    
    def getCurrentPosition(self):
        return self.currentPosition
    
    def getSpecies(self):
        return self.species
    
    def advancePosition():
        pass
    
    def setSpeed(self, newSpeed):
        self.speed = newSpeed
    
    def setNapStart(self, newNapStart):
        self.napStart = newNapStart
    
    def setNapDuration(self, newNapDuration):
        self.napDuration = newNapDuration
    
    def setCurrentPosition(self, newCurrentPosition):
        self.currentPosition = newCurrentPosition
```

> Then we have the race code which doesn't work yet because I have no idea how to make them move in the first place

```
class Race:
    
    def __init__(self, eventName, distance, contestant1, contestant2):
        self.eventName = eventName
        self.distance = distance
        self.contestant1 = contestant1
        self.contestant2 = contestant2
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.eventName) + " " + str(self.distance) + " " + str(self.contestant1) + " " + str(self.contestant2)
    
    def getEventName(self):
        return self.eventName
    
    def getDistance(self):
        return self.distance
    
    def runRace(self):
        pass
```

> The last thing I have are just tester animals so you get an idea of what they do kind of?

```
tortoise = animal("tort", "tortoise", 2, 0, 0, 0)
hare = animal("harry", "hare", 10, 5, 20, 0)
```

> And this is for the race code

```
race1 = Race("the race", 30, tortoise, hare)
```

> Thank you so much for your help and if you need more info I can totally give it to you :)

Comment: Python is not Java.. This looks more like Java with setters and getters.

Comment: I'm doing this is python! I haven't experienced Java so I wouldn't really know :(

Comment: @Fallette this is probably not the best tutorial for learning *python* the language, which does not idiomatically write getters and setters. Often, a lot of tutorials were written by people who are used to teaching Java. You can still learn OOP, but Python style would not be like this.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not definitely not saying you or Austin were wrong! I just found out about OOP this week in my class and I just have to do this as an assignment in python. I don't know about any other languages and I'm trying to learn how but I hope I can do better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def runRace(self):
    time = 0
    while self.contestant1.getCurrentPosition() < self.getDistance() and self.contestant2.getCurrentPosition() < self.getDistance():
        time += 1
        if self.contestant2.getNapStart() > time or self.contestant2.getNapStart() + self.contestant2.getNapDuration < time:
            self.contestant1.advancePosition()
        self.contestant1.advancePosition()
    if self.contestant1.getCurrentPosition > self.contestant2.getCurrentPosition:
        return self.contestant1
    else: 
        return self.contestant2



def advancePosition():
    self.currentPosition += self.getSpeed()


winner = race1.runRace()
print(winner.getName())
```

Careful, only contestant2 can nap in this example code (should always be the hare)

Answer (score 0):

The method `advancePosition(self)` likely just adds the speed of the animal to the position (i.e. Tortoise travels 3 units/second, so in 1 second his position will now be 3). Just call this every update.

I'm not sure what "naps" are for or what the logic is for this race but that should be a start.

Comment: so I would most likely update the current position attribute by the speed of the animal everytime the race updates? Also, the nap portion is for the hare!

Comment: Yes that would be correct! Then I'm guessing after such and such seconds, make the hate not move (nap) for the specified duration while continuing to move the tortoise

Comment: Does not make sense to me (yet?). Why is the hare napping? If its intended to make the hare slower than the tortoise, you could just use a slower speed - but this isn't even necessary, since the hare is intended to win the race. The analogy is that the tortoise is given a starting advantage (100 units or so), and then it is to find out at what point the hare takes the lead with his higher speed (or if he manages to take the lead within the distance of the race). IMO get rid of all the napping methods, except if the winner is allowed to nap after he crossed the finish line.

Comment: In the fable of the tortoise and the hare, the hare takes a nap toward the end of the race because he's too cocky. This causes him to lose to the slower tortoise. I imagine it's just a recreation of that fable as oppose to the "who gets there first" experiment

Comment: Yeah nevermind, I was thinking of an ancient greek thought-experiment and never heard of the 1912 fable. Basically the thought-experiment is interested in the exact position the hare does / can still take the lead over the tortoise "after he naps" (analogous to giving the tortoise a starting advantage). Recreating this race is missing a lot of parameters tho; at what point does the hare start napping? For how long? how long is the race? Whats the speed difference between them? etc... etc... the greek story is just a lot more straight-forward because the hare "naps" at the start of the race.

Comment: Yeah I know the one you are talking about. And what's cool is that the OP can recreate that experiment too! The start of the nap and it's duration are set during the initialization of the animal. Setting both to 0 for both animals means that neither nap and you can set other methods to check for the point where they cross. Which I think is more interesting practice code but this version is okay too lol

Comment: Well if neither naps, they "cross" at the start of the race (at which point the winner is determined). Typically, you'd let the hare nap for 10 seconds, and set his speed to 10x the tortoise's speed and determine the point / time at which the hare takes the lead. This is basically "part 2" of the race, which needs to return "false".

Comment: Yes you're right. Setting nap duration at the start is required for that particular experiment